# ORA- 00936 Missing Expression in From

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

Here is what I have;

```
SELECT course.course_no, enrollment.grade, 
FROM course, enrollment, course_section, student
WHERE course.course_no=course_section.course_no, 
course_section.c_sec_id=enrollment.c_sec_id, enrollment.s_id=student.s_id
AND student.s_first='Tammy', student.s_last='Jones';


FROM course, enrollment, course_section, student    
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after last column and also in your where clause, you should use AND and not COMMA
Try this

```
SELECT course.course_no, enrollment.grade
FROM course, enrollment, course_section, student
WHERE course.course_no=course_section.course_no AND  
course_section.c_sec_id=enrollment.c_sec_id AND 
enrollment.s_id=student.s_id AND 
student.s_first='Tammy' AND 
student.s_last='Jones';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` instead of `,` in `WHERE` caluse. Also remove the last extra comma from the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT course.course_no, enrollment.grade
FROM   course, 
       enrollment, 
       course_section, 
       student
WHERE  course.course_no = course_section.course_no        
AND    course_section.c_sec_id=enrollment.c_sec_id        
AND    enrollment.s_id=student.s_id
AND    student.s_first='Tammy'
AND    student.s_last='Jones';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is improperly formed.

When you have multiple parts to WHERE clause, they must be explicitly stated and not just separated by commas:

```
SELECT course.course_no, enrollment.grade, 
FROM course, enrollment, course_section, student
WHERE course.course_no=course_section.course_no
AND course_section.c_sec_id=enrollment.c_sec_id
AND   enrollment.s_id=student.s_id
AND student.s_first='Tammy'
AND student.s_last='Jones';
```